# style="display: none" superseding css currentcamera wordpress athena theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Ok so Im using a wordpress theme called Athena that uses a camera.js plugin.  In the html I have a main page button div that is set to block where after a couple seconds it disappears and changes to display:none. I can change it back to display:block in the console but I can't find the source where this change is happening. I dont want the div to disappear. There is no line number next to it. I think its taking place in a .js file and superseding the css. I tried command+f in the camera.js file as well as the css file and highlighted anything with display: and tried changing anything with none to block but that didn't work. Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <div class="cameraContent cameracurrent" style="/* display: none; */"><div class="overlay"></div>    This is what the html looks like after it disappears

Comment: Try to inspect button and make sure where changes happen, or use inline styling

Comment: Post a link to your page.

Comment: I inspect the button and tried inline styling, but the div isnt in the main html, its created in the javascript somewhere but I cant seem to find it

Comment: http://www.domcreates.xyz/

Comment: the buttons on the main page disappear after 3 or 4 seconds if you click the url.

Comment: If it's Wordpress, there's a good chance jQuery is involved so look for `.hide`, `.toggle`, `.fadeOut` or `.slideUp`. All of those methods hide an element

Comment: which button? i cannot see the button.

Comment: If you're just looking for an _override_ of the _override_ use this `.camera_fakehover > .camera_target_content > div > div {
    display: initial !important;
}` but that's just a lazy way to address this.

Comment: hmmm, theres over 2000 lines of code with a lot of .hides.   To vel, if you cannot see the buttons in the main header picture, refresh your screen, it might have already disappeared

Comment: That lazy way worked I haz, except it disappears for a second first then comes back. Im sure theres some fadeout I have to find and disable but at least thats a temp solution, thanks

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try changing the ` fadeout` value in line 1090 of `camera.js` Here's what it looks like by default  `$('.cameraContent',fakeHover).fadeOut(600);`

Comment: yeah, it worked. Thanks i haz kode

Comment: issue with your camera slider. try to add one some slider and check

Comment: @DominicZenon Great to know that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used the browser inspection tools to find out what class was getting the `display:none` property applied to it. 
I then used the information you provided in your question - namely the name of the file `camera.js`

I searched the file for the class name I mentioned above. I found three different results.

This is the most likely one:
try changing the `fadeout` value in `line 1090` of `camera.js` Here's what it looks like by default

```
$('.cameraContent',fakeHover).fadeOut(600);
```